# Lebesgue's measure problem...

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $D\subseteq [0,1]^d$ be the Lebesgue's measure-zero set and $g:[0,1]^d\rightarrow [0,1]^d$ be a bounded function
such that $u+g(u)\in [0,1]^d$ for all $u\in [0,1]^d$.
Define 
$$S:=\{u\in[0,1]^d: \lambda_1(S_u)=0\},$$
where $S_u:=\{s\in[0,1]: u+sg(u)\notin [0,1]^d\setminus D\}$ and $\lambda_d$ denotes the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. 
We want to show that

$$\lambda_d(S)=1.$$

Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first line, "bounded" is not necessary. Maybe you wanted to write "measurable", or "Borel"?